# Matlab: Setting ButtonDownFcn disables default datatip functionality on hover

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am looking into enabling hover and click actions for a plot in Matlab.
Matlab nicely has the builtin feature of viewing the data tips when hovering on a point in a plot.
However, when I try to set the ButtonDownFcn action of the plot, this default data tip functionality is disabled.
Is there a way to have both: View data points on hover and fire a function when the plot is clicked?

Example:

```
figure()
a=plot(1:10,1:10)
%Figure now shows data tips perfectly
set(a,'HitTest', 'on', 'ButtonDownFcn',@(varargin)disp('Anything'))
%Running the last line disables the datatips on hovering to enable firing the disp function when plot is clicked
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the `DataTipTemplate` property of `a` changed after updating the `HitTest` and `ButtonDownFcn`? Is `a.DataTipTemplate` different before and after?

Comment: No, it's the same..a.DataTipTemplate.DataTipRows is the same as well